# Можно ли computed вытащить как отдельный компонент

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть страница добовления уроков. На этой странице выбор учителей и сам список учителей обрабатывается в компьютед. Могу я этот блок сделать компонентом. Будет ли там computed так же работать?

Comment: Что значит компонентом? computed - это данные, а не компонент

Comment: Думаю, я неправильно выразилась. Список учителей у меня динамичный и он обрабатываться должен в computed. Если блок списка я сделаю компонентом, то будет ли он таким же динамичным?

Comment: Элемент списка = компонент, в компонент через `props` передаете данные, в этом компоненте обрабатываете через `computed` свойство и вставляете в компонент. Так можно. Это то, что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: да, благодарю  !